# How to get data from a rejected promise

Tags: javascript, json, handle

I need the specific data about why a request didn't work (existing username or occupied email) the console only throw a "Bad Request" error but doesn't specify. I saw I can return the promise that cointains data errors, but I don't know how to extract that info or how to receive a json with the reason

[Image of the promise with the specific erors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4HkH.jpg)

Comment: The promise in your image hasn't been rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The promise will only return the reason as to why the promise was rejected. If you wanted to check for username / email availability, you would have to create a custom check against your database and provide a handler for the returned values.